# Code works in java but not in c# or no equivalent is found

Tags: java, c#, selenium, webdriver

I m trying to click on each link on a web page (selenium + C#) . the code below works in java but trying to get it to work in c# is challenging. the issues i encounter is the get[i] and chord in the code. i cant find equivalent in C#. the rest of the code works apart from the get[i] and chord. any ideas how to convert these two in the for loop to c# please or modify the last 2 lines of code? the logic of the code definitely works in java.

```cs
IWebElement links3 = OpenPageSteps.driver1.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='content']/ul"));
Console.WriteLine(links3.FindElements(By.TagName("a")).Count());
for (int i=0; i<links3.FindElements(By.TagName("a")).Count; i++)
{
    string opentabs = Keys.Chord(Keys.Control,Keys.Enter);
    links3.FindElements(By.TagName("a")).get[i].SendKeys(opentabs);
}
```

Comment: I think you'll just want list_object[i] instead of .get...  I believe keychords are deprecated.  Use SendKeys(Keys.Control, Keys.Return)

Comment: Do you mean something like this? links3.FindElements(By.TagName("a")).list_object[i].SendKeys(opentabs); it doesnt like it

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `get` keyword. You can simply use the indexer with `[]`

```cs
IWebElement links3 = OpenPageSteps.driver1.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='content']/ul"));
ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> aTags =  links3.FindElements(By.TagName("a"));
Console.WriteLine(aTags.Count);
for (int i = 0; i < aTags.Count; i++)
{
    aTags[i].SendKeys(Keys.Control + Keys.Enter);
}
```

or, even better, use `foreach`:

```cs
foreach (IWebElement element in aTags)
{
    element.SendKeys(Keys.Control + Keys.Enter);
}
```

You can simply use `+` to combine the keys.

The `ReadOnlyCollection` has a `Count` property. No need to call the less efficient LINQ `Count()` method.

Also, first store the result in a temp, instead of repeating the same `FindElements` 3 times.

Comment: thanks. would it be possible to check that each page loaded will load correctly and not return 404 page not found? i m thinking of  adding another for loop with the main loop

Comment: You should find the reason why 404 is returned and remove the error.